# Is it possible to exchange seeds in uTorrent?

Tags: bittorrent, utorrent

Lets say a torrent release has 100 seeds, and I am connected to 10 of them right now. If  those seeds have very bad upload speed (I can see it from peer stats), can I add those seeds to a blacklist or something and connect to 10 different ones instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All clients based upon BitTorrent (including uTorrent) have a setting in the Preferences, under the Advanced tab, below the "gui_" section, that says ipfilter_enable.

If you enable this, then create/download an ipfilter.dat file & add the IP of the machine you wish to block, & restart uTorrent, any IP you choose can be blocked.

As for adding peers, just select the torrent in your list, open the Peers tab, right click inside it & choose Add Peer, then paste the IP of your buddy.

Answer (score 0):

I have used torrents for a long time and have never came across a blacklisting feature in any torrent clients. I know this doesn't answer your question but its the best i can do.